# How to get all pending transactions

Tags: pending-transactions, txpool, openethereum

I want to use my open-ethereum node to get all the pending transactions. How can I do it?

The `eth_getBlockByNumber` API returns only about a hundred and according to Etherscan there are 150,000 pending transactions.

In addition `eth_getBlockTransactionCountByNumber` with "pending" as block number returns that there are 0 transactions. And `parity_allTransactions` also does not find any transactions.

I also tried playing with `--tx-queue-mem-limit` and `--tx-queue-size` configurations but they didn't seem to change anything.

Any ideas?